# Call Git Workflows on demand like function calls

Tags: github-actions

We have a large workflow where we deploy multiple components at a single go. But I am trying to break them down into smaller deployments.

If I am deploying all, I expect the deployment should follow the sequence of prepare-> A -> B and so on. This is fine. But I also want ability to deploy C alone sometime or B alone without running prepare or Job A. Is this possible or my approach is correct way to deploy

```
job prepare:
  # run first
job A:
  # deploys A
job B:
  needs: job A
  # deploys B
job C:
  needs: job B
  # deploys C
job D:
  # deploys D
```

Comment: You could leverage [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) for this? This gives you a `uses:` directive at the job level.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. So should I break down the jobs as individual work flows and calls them using workflow_call? Or Job itself works?

Comment: Even though they're called "reusable *workflows*", they're really more like "reusable jobs": they replace the details of a job, but triggers etc. are all handled in the calling workflow. They can comprise multiple jobs, though.